# How to predict single value using function fitted()?

Tags: r, model, regression, predict

Let's consider model following :

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- data.frame('Exp' = rexp(100),'Poiss' = rpois(100,1))
model_1 <- lm(y~., data = x)
```

I want to predict value for `model_1` of (Exp = 1, Poiss = 0.5).

To do this I used code : `fitted(model_1, data.frame(Exp = 1, Poiss =0.5))`.

However I get 100 values instead of one predicted. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#Code
predict(model_1, data.frame(Exp = 1, Poiss =0.5))
```

Because `fitted()` does this:

> fitted is a generic function which extracts fitted values from objects
> returned by modeling functions. fitted.values is an alias for it.

That is why you are getting 100 values, as this is extracting the data fitted from the original `model_1`.